# BAREOS 16.2.4 interrupted by signal 11: Segmentation violation in Debian 8?

Tags: debian, segmentation-fault, bareos

I have a BareOS director I'm trying to start on Debian 8, and when it starts up I get the following error:

```
-- Logs begin at Wed 2017-06-28 16:36:57 UTC, end at Wed 2017-06-28 16:50:26 UTC. --
Jun 28 16:44:40 bareOSdirector systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Bareos Director...
Jun 28 16:44:41 bareOSdirector bareos-dir[9337]: Checking Configuration and Database connection ...
Jun 28 16:44:41 bareOSdirector su[9340]: Successful su for bareos by root
Jun 28 16:44:41 bareOSdirector su[9340]: + ??? root:bareos
Jun 28 16:44:41 bareOSdirector su[9340]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user bareos by (uid=0)
Jun 28 16:44:41 bareOSdirector bareos-dir[9337]: BAREOS interrupted by signal 11: Segmentation violation
Jun 28 16:44:41 bareOSdirector bareos-dir[9342]: BAREOS interrupted by signal 11: Segmentation violation
Jun 28 16:44:41 bareOSdirector bareos-dir[9337]: Kaboom! bareos-dir, bareos-dir got signal 11 - Segmentation violation. Attempting traceback.
Jun 28 16:44:41 bareOSdirector bareos-dir[9337]: Kaboom! exepath=/usr/sbin/
Jun 28 16:44:41 bareOSdirector bareos-dir[9337]: Calling: /usr/sbin/btraceback /usr/sbin/bareos-dir 9342 /var/lib/bareos
Jun 28 16:44:41 bareOSdirector bareos-dir[9337]: It looks like the traceback worked...
Jun 28 16:44:41 bareOSdirector bareos-dir[9337]: Dumping: /var/lib/bareos/bareos-dir.9342.bactrace
Jun 28 16:44:41 bareOSdirector su[9340]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user bareos
Jun 28 16:44:41 bareOSdirector systemd[1]: Started LSB: Bareos Director.
```

It appears that it is related to the configuration in some way:

Okay I found more details here:

```
vagrant@bareOSdirector:~$  /usr/sbin/bareos-dir -t -d 200 -u bareos -g bareos
bareos-dir (10): dird.c:243-0 Debug level = 200
bareos-dir (100): parse_conf.c:151-0 config file = /etc/bareos/bareos-dir.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/bareos-dir.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/bareos-dir.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: |find /etc/bareos/director.d -name '*.conf' -type f -exec echo @{} ;
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/pool-Scratch.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/pool-Scratch.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/fileset-SelfTest.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/fileset-SelfTest.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/messages-Daemon.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/messages-Daemon.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/job-lampdir-fd-RestoreFiles.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/job-lampdir-fd-RestoreFiles.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/fileset-Catalog.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/fileset-Catalog.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/pool-Differential.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/pool-Differential.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/fileset-bacula_files_backup.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/fileset-bacula_files_backup.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/schedule-WeeklyCycle.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/schedule-WeeklyCycle.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/storage-File.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/storage-File.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/job-lampdir-fd-BaculaDirectorDirFiles.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/job-lampdir-fd-BaculaDirectorDirFiles.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/pool-Full.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/pool-Full.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/messages-standard.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/messages-standard.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/fileset-LinuxAll.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/fileset-LinuxAll.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/pool-Incremental.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/pool-Incremental.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/catalog-MyCatalog.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/catalog-MyCatalog.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/job-lampdir-fd-BackupCatalog.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/job-lampdir-fd-BackupCatalog.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: |find /etc/bareos/clients.d -name '*.conf' -type f -exec echo @{} ;
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/clients.d/lampdir-fd.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/clients.d/lampdir-fd.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/bareos-dir.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/bareos-dir.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: |find /etc/bareos/director.d -name '*.conf' -type f -exec echo @{} ;
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/pool-Scratch.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/pool-Scratch.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/fileset-SelfTest.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/fileset-SelfTest.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/messages-Daemon.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/messages-Daemon.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/job-lampdir-fd-RestoreFiles.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/job-lampdir-fd-RestoreFiles.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/fileset-Catalog.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/fileset-Catalog.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/pool-Differential.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/pool-Differential.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/fileset-bacula_files_backup.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/fileset-bacula_files_backup.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/schedule-WeeklyCycle.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/schedule-WeeklyCycle.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/storage-File.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/storage-File.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/job-lampdir-fd-BaculaDirectorDirFiles.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/job-lampdir-fd-BaculaDirectorDirFiles.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/pool-Full.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/pool-Full.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/messages-standard.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/messages-standard.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/fileset-LinuxAll.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/fileset-LinuxAll.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/pool-Incremental.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/pool-Incremental.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/catalog-MyCatalog.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/catalog-MyCatalog.conf
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/director.d/job-lampdir-fd-BackupCatalog.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/director.d/job-lampdir-fd-BackupCatalog.conf
bareos-dir (200): runscript.c:334-0 runscript: debug
bareos-dir (200): runscript.c:335-0  --> RunScript
bareos-dir (200): runscript.c:336-0   --> Command=/usr/lib/bareos/scripts/make_catalog_backup.pl MyCatalog
bareos-dir (200): runscript.c:337-0   --> Target=%c
bareos-dir (200): runscript.c:338-0   --> RunOnSuccess=1
bareos-dir (200): runscript.c:339-0   --> RunOnFailure=0
bareos-dir (200): runscript.c:340-0   --> FailJobOnError=1
bareos-dir (200): runscript.c:341-0   --> RunWhen=2
bareos-dir (200): runscript.c:334-0 runscript: debug
bareos-dir (200): runscript.c:335-0  --> RunScript
bareos-dir (200): runscript.c:336-0   --> Command=/usr/lib/bareos/scripts/delete_catalog_backup
bareos-dir (200): runscript.c:337-0   --> Target=%c
bareos-dir (200): runscript.c:338-0   --> RunOnSuccess=1
bareos-dir (200): runscript.c:339-0   --> RunOnFailure=0
bareos-dir (200): runscript.c:340-0   --> FailJobOnError=0
bareos-dir (200): runscript.c:341-0   --> RunWhen=1
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: |find /etc/bareos/clients.d -name '*.conf' -type f -exec echo @{} ;
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:356-0 glob /etc/bareos/clients.d/lampdir-fd.conf: 1 files
bareos-dir (100): lex.c:250-0 open config file: /etc/bareos/clients.d/lampdir-fd.conf


BAREOS interrupted by signal 11: Segmentation violation
Kaboom! bareos-dir, bareos-dir got signal 11 - Segmentation violation. Attempting traceback.
Kaboom! exepath=/usr/sbin/
Calling: /usr/sbin/btraceback /usr/sbin/bareos-dir 10692 /var/lib/bareos
/usr/sbin/btraceback: 94: /usr/sbin/btraceback: cannot create /var/lib/bareos/bareos.10692.traceback: Permission denied
cat: /var/lib/bareos/bareos.10692.traceback: No such file or directory

It looks like the traceback worked...
Dumping: /var/lib/bareos/bareos-dir.10692.bactrace
Attempt to dump locks
Attempt to dump current JCRs. njcrs=0
```

It appears that the last file processed is `/etc/bareos/clients.d/lampdir-fd.conf` :

```
Client {
  Name = "lampdir-fd"
  Address = localhost
  FDPort = 9102
  Password = "blah"
  Catalog = "MyCatalog"
  FileRetention = 30 days
  JobRetention = 6 months
  AutoPrune = true
  HeartbeatInterval = 1 minute
}
```

Not certain what the issue with it is...

Comment: I believe it may actually be the configuration: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/bareos-users/$20Kaboom!$20bareos-dir$2C$20bareos-dir$20got$20signal$2011|sort:relevance/bareos-users/2AjM9gG6WdI/EmLcFkB7AAAJ ran `/usr/sbin/bareos-dir -t -d 200 -u bareos -g bareos` and the config-file causing the issue becomes apparent

Comment: It's kinda neat that it detects the segfault and runs a backtrace. Or worrisome that released code segfaults enough to require that...

Comment: Okay so I was missing a `JobDef`.